# Modular CMS for static HTML sites

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system

Are there any modular, lightweight content management systems for websites that start as static HTML?

To be more specific, there are a number of clients who would like to edit content on very specific areas of the website (i.e. the hours, the special events, etc..) but those are the only things on the website they would ever want to change themselves. Typically the company I work for has used WordPress, but lately I've been noticing it being unnecessarily bulky for the functionality we are actually using.

Ideally it would be something as basic as a login portal that redirects to the homepage after you log in, then the editable area would append an (edit) link which would pop a plain text editor up.

I've seen of couchCMS and cushyCMS but haven't heard anything about them, I've also looked into trying to build a simple CMS but I still have more to learn in PHP and MySQL before I'm comfortable.

P.S. I've read the "what questions to ask" section for a while before I decided to post this here, I know it's not very specific of a coding question but if you know of a better exchange site to ask this, I'll promptly delete and repost there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit open ended, ie we don't know all your requirements, budget, timelines etc, so an "answer" is hard. All I can give you are options/advice.

Have you tried searching on Stack sites and Google (etc) for "content management system" and reviewing what each one offers?

Drupal is lightweight-ish as it allows a basic package then bolt on features you want.

However, whatever CMS you decide to go with, bear in mind most CMSs are designed to cater for much more than what you want. Most try to provide for forums/blogs/sites with shops, etc. Generally, they wouldn't spend months planning and developing, and continuing to release bug fixes/security updates/etc for something that just managed a bit of text here and there.

> clients would like to edit content on very specific areas of the website (i.e. the hours, the special events, etc..) but those are the only things on the website they would ever want to change themselves

This is very simple. It might be worth hiring a freelancer/dev company to create your own simple CMS that would store the data you want changing in a DB and give you/your clients some simple form fields to edit and save them.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Yea I realize the question is a bit open ended, which is why I was reluctant to post it initially. I did more research and it became clear that I didn't know just how many different options were out there.

Answer (score 0):

Do not go for Drupal whatever you do. It was a nightmare. We are now using wordpress as its much cleaner code and simpler to modify and customize. However it seems you need something even simpler than wordpress.

There are very simple cms's out there that allow you to include as little as one javascript file in your html page and you can then define areas in the page to make editable.

Best place to check out is http://www.opensourcecms.com/

You will probably want to look at the "lite" category

for an example of a javascript only system check out "99ko 1.2.7"
http://www.opensourcecms.com/scripts/details.php?scriptid=638&name=99ko

good luck!

Comment: You can try [objengine](http://www.objengine.com)